# 3D plot of spheres

Tags: python-3.x, 3d

I am trying to make a 3D plot of randomized spheres. I had this working in a 2D plot, and now I would like to visualize it in 3D. It is not working as of right now, and I am not sure exactly what is going on. This is what I have so far.

```
'''import random
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as lines
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

class Circle:
  def __init__(self, x, y, z, radius):
    self.x_ = x
    self.y_ = y
    self.z_ = z
    self.radius_ = radius

def distance(circle1, circle2):
  return math.sqrt((circle1.x_ - circle2.x_)**2 + (circle1.y_ - circle2.y_)**2 + (circle1.z_ - circle2.z_)**2)

def main():

  random.seed(1)

  radius_large = float(input("Enter the radius of the large circles: "))
  radius_small = float(input("Enter the radius of the small circles: "))

  # Slice the square into a grid - width, height, depth 
  grid_minw = 6*radius_large
  grid_minh = 6*radius_large
  grid_mind = 6*radius_large

  n_gridX = math.floor(1/grid_minw)
  n_gridY = math.floor(1/grid_minh)
  n_gridZ = math.floor(1/grid_mind)

  actualgrid_w = 1/n_gridX
  actualgrid_h = 1/n_gridY
  actualgrid_d = 1/n_gridZ

  v_sphere_large = [[[ [] for _ in range(n_gridX)] for _ in range(n_gridY)] for _ in range(n_gridZ)]

  # First, add the large spheres
  n_addspheres = 1
  while n_addspheres > 0:

    n_addspheres = 0
    for _ in range(1000):
      x = random.uniform(radius_large, 1-radius_large)
      y = random.uniform(radius_large, 1-radius_large)
      z = random.uniform(radius_large, 1-radius_large)
      c_candidate_large = Circle(x, y, z, radius_large)

      #grid indicies for large grid
      grid_i = math.floor(x/actualgrid_w)
      grid_j = math.floor(y/actualgrid_h)
      grid_k = math.floor(z/actualgrid_d)

      #print("Candidate sphere position and grid indices: ("+str(x)+", "+str(y)+", "+str(z)+"), ["+str(grid_i)+", "+str(grid_j)+", "+str(grid_k)+"]")
      b_overlap = False
      for i in range(max(0, grid_i-1), min(grid_i+2, n_gridX)):
        for j in range(max(0, grid_j-1), min(grid_j+2, n_gridY)):
          for k in range(max(0, grid_k-1), min(grid_k+1, n_gridZ)):
            if len(v_sphere_large[i][j][k]) > 0:
              for c_iteration in v_sphere_large[i][j][k]:
                if distance(c_candidate_large, c_iteration) < c_iteration.radius_ + c_candidate_large.radius_:
                  b_overlap = True
                  break
      if not b_overlap:
        v_sphere_large[grid_i][grid_j][grid_k].append(c_candidate_large)
        n_addspheres += 1

  #Small grid information
  grid_small_minw = 6*radius_small
  grid_small_minh = 6*radius_small
  grid_small_mind = 6*radius_small

  n_gridX_small = math.floor(1/grid_small_minw)
  n_gridY_small = math.floor(1/grid_small_minh)
  n_gridZ_small = math.floor(1/grid_small_mind)

  actualgrid_w_small = 1/n_gridX_small
  actualgrid_h_small = 1/n_gridY_small
  actualgrid_d_small = 1/n_gridZ_small

  v_sphere_small = [[[ [] for _ in range (n_gridX_small)] for _ in range(n_gridY_small)] for _ in range(n_gridZ_small)]
  n_addspheres = 1
  while n_addspheres > 0:

    n_addspheres = 0
    for _ in range(1000):
      x = random.uniform(radius_small, 1-radius_small)
      y = random.uniform(radius_small, 1-radius_small)
      z = random.uniform(radius_small, 1-radius_small)
      c_candidate_small = Circle(x, y, z, radius_small)

      #grid indicies for big grid 
      grid_i_large = math.floor(x/actualgrid_w)
      grid_j_large = math.floor(y/actualgrid_h)
      grid_k_large = math.floor(z/actualgrid_d)

      #grid indicides in the small grid 
      grid_i_small = math.floor(x/actualgrid_w_small)
      grid_j_small = math.floor(y/actualgrid_h_small)
      grid_k_small = math.floor(z/actualgrid_d_small)

       #print("Candidate circle pos and grid : ("+str(x)+", "+str(y)+", "+str(z)+"), ["+str(grid_i_small)+", "+str(grid_j_small)+", "+str(grid_k_small)+"]")

      # Check for overlap with big circles first, then small circles
      b_overlap = False
      s_overlap = False
      for i in range(max(0,grid_i_large-1), min(grid_i_large+2, n_gridX)):
        for j in range(max(0,grid_j_large-1), min(grid_j_large+2, n_gridY)):
          for k in range(max(0,grid_k_large-1), min(grid_k_large+2, n_gridZ)):
            if len(v_sphere_large[i][j][k]) > 0:
              for c_iteration in v_sphere_large[i][j][k]:
                if distance(c_candidate_small, c_iteration) < c_iteration.radius_ + c_candidate_small.radius_:
                  b_overlap = True
                  break
      if not b_overlap:
        for i in range(max(0, grid_i_small-1), min(grid_i_small+2, n_gridX_small)):
          for j in range(max(0, grid_j_small-1), min(grid_j_small+2, n_gridY_small)):
            for k in range(max(0, grid_k_small-1), min(grid_k_small+2, n_gridZ_small)):
              if len(v_sphere_small[i][j][k]) > 0:
                for c_iteration in v_sphere_small[i][j][k]:
                  if distance(c_candidate_small, c_iteration) < c_iteration.radius_ + c_candidate_small.radius_:
                    s_overlap = True
                    break
      if not s_overlap and not b_overlap:
        v_sphere_small[grid_i_small][grid_j_small][grid_k_small].append(c_candidate_small)
        n_addspheres += 1

  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
  num_spheres_large=0
  num_spheres_small=0
  num_spheres_total=0
  for sublist in v_sphere_large:
    for next_list in sublist:
      for inn_list in next_list:
        for sphere in inn_list:
          ax.add_artist(plt.Circle((sphere.x_, sphere.y_, sphere.z_), radius=sphere.radius_, alpha=0.5, color='b'))
   for sublist in v_sphere_small:
     for next_list in sublist:
      for inn_list in next_list:
        for sphere in inn_list:
          ax.add_artist(plt.Circle((sphere.x_, sphere.y_, sphere.z_), radius=sphere.radius_))


  # Set axis limits and aspect ratio
  ax.set_xlim3d(0, 1.)
  ax.set_ylim3d(0, 1.)
  ax.set_zlim3d(0, 1.)
  ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')


  # Display the plot
  plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()'''
```

I've made some changes to it already so the class circle takes in a z argument and all of the spheres are stored in lists, I'm just not sure how to go through the lists and plot the spheres that way.

Comment: I don't believe `matplotlib`'s `Circle` plotting is capable of plotting in 3d.  You probably need to use a different package or plot a wireframe of the sphere.  (Google it)